# What is wrong with writing two location in nginx.conf and getting 404 error?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

This is my **nginx.conf** file content:

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /prometheus/ {
            proxy_pass http://prometheus:9090/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location /grafana/ {
            proxy_pass http://grafana:3000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

when I change `/prometheus/` or `/grafana/` to `/`, the application works correctly, but when I write a word after `/` I get 404 error!

**All of the applications are running by docker. (If it helps)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, ensure that the location path /prometheus/ in your Nginx configuration matches the URL path you are using to access your application. For example, if you are trying to access the application at http://prometheus:9090/prometheus/, the configuration you provided should work.

Be aware that whether you include a trailing slash in your location and proxy_pass can affect the behavior. In your case, /prometheus/ is matched only when there's a trailing slash in the URL. If you want to make it work with or without the trailing slash, you can use the rewrite directive to enforce a consistent behavior:

```
location /prometheus/ {
    rewrite ^/prometheus(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://prometheus:9090;
}
```

Also do tail the logs and see if there is something useful there when you try to hit the URL

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Not to mention, the 404 error in the configuration you've provided could be caused by several other factors too.